# Re-using tests among Geb Specs

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I am trying to re-use a Geb Spec test I wrote in another Geb Spec so I won't need to re-write code. I always need the product number in different pages so I would like to do something similar to the following;

```
class BasePageGebSpec extends GebReportingSpec {
     def firstProductOnBrowsePage(){
        when:
        to BrowsePage
        then:
        waitFor { BrowsePage }
        productId { $("meta", 0, itemprop: "mpn").@content }
        return productID // ???
    } 
}
```

And in another GebSpec I wish to use the above `firstProductOnBrowsePage` like below:

```
 class ProductDetailsPageGebSpec extends BasePageGebSpec {
     def "See first products details page"(){
        when:
        to ProductDetailsPage, productId: firstProductOnBrowsePage()

       then:
       waitFor { $("h2", class:"title").size() != 0 }
       assert true
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [traits](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-traits.html) you can almost get what you want (tests don't work within a trait however).  You might also consider creating a spec class that tests the product number for every page you have, and then not worrying about testing this functionality within each individual page's spec class.

```
trait BasePageGebSpec extends GebReportingSpec {
 def testingFirstBrowse() {
    waitFor { BrowsePage }
    productId { $("meta", 0, itemprop: "mpn").@content }
    return productID
 }
}

 class ProductDetailsPageGebSpec implements BasePageGebSpec {
    def firstProductOnBrowsePage(){
        when:
            to BrowsePage
        then:
            testingFirstBrowse()
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't get the example. `GebReportingSpec` is a class and a trait can only extend other traits, so I just get a compilation issue if I define a trait like you have.

Comment: You're correct. I should have used 'implements' instead of 'extends'; and it assumes GebReportingSpec is a trait. The most important takeaway is that Spock tests don't work inside a trait. At best you could externalize a method with some of the common test code, but you'll still need a test for it in each separate Spec class.

Answer (score 0):

Add productId as content on the `BrowsePage`:

```
class BrowsePage extends Page {
  static content = {
    productId { $("meta", 0, itemprop: "mpn").@content }
  }
}
```

and then use it in your spec:

```
class ProductDetailsPageGebSpec extends BasePageGebSpec {
  def "See first products details page"(){
    when:
    to ProductDetailsPage, productId: to(BrowsePage).productId

    then:
    waitFor { $("h2", class:"title").size() != 0 }
  }
}
```